# Ruby/Sinatra Hangs on HTTP Request

Tags: ruby, sinatra

New to Ruby

Fresh install ubuntu, ruby, rvm, gems, sinatra, nginx, passenger

Attempting to run simple hello world app. I can get the app to run using thin, ie rackup config.ru. Unable to get anything to run through nginx/passenger. If i create an error in the config.ru file then I get the error page from passenger. Leads me to believe that this issue is unrelated to nginx.

My guess is there is some issue with the run line within the config.ru, my lack of knowledge with ruby is a creating a roadblock as to why. On top, cannot find any similar issues online.

Edit: Just to clarify, by "unable to get anything to run", my http request to the server goes ignored and the browser will just sit forever trying to load.

app.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "Hello and Goodbye"
end
```

config.ru

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

nginx config

```
http {
passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/passenger-3.0.19;
passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p385/ruby;

include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

sendfile        on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    access_log  /srv/www-logs/test.access.log;
    error_log /srv/www-logs/test.error.log;
    root /srv/www/test/public;
    passenger_enabled on;

    location /static {
        root   /srv/www/test/public;
        index  index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the request isn't being forwarded from nginx to your web application. What's the nginx configuration?

Comment: i added the core of the nginx config. The reason I did not think this was the problem is because I can see output if I set me config.ru incorrectly, that is I can hit the url and see a passenger / ruby error page.

Comment: Try `require './app.rb'` instead of just `./app`

Comment: "cannot load such file -- ./app.ru". I can see the passenger/ruby error screen. Which led me to believe ./app worked and it was hanging up with require Sinatra::Application.

Comment: app.rb, not .ru. It should be the exact name (and location) of your app.rb file.

Comment: Crap typo on my part. So in the folder hierarchy I have app.rb in the root of my app folder, same location as config.ru. I changed it to require './app.rb' and I get Not Found displayed when I get the site. I could not find the most exact information on how to include the ruby file in the root of my app directory. Thoughts?

Comment: Ok tweaked some stuff and got it running, you nailed it. Cannot believe it was just a typo that I kept making. Anyway thanks, please post an answer so I can give you the solve. thanks!